# Issues Running react project, SEVERAL module not found errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, terminal

so I'm trying to run this one react project (one that I've run SEVERAL times & has worked SEVERAL TIMES before), but for some reason, it just doesn't work and just won't give me a break. I'm struggling to see why I'm getting such a ridiculous amount of errors. I have the most up to date npm version installed I run 'npm install' command prior. Please help me out if you can. Thank you.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 24:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/dotenv/lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 26:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js 39:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/address.js 14:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js 14:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/helpers.js 11:12-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 43:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/Users/tazar/nft-minter-tutorial/minter-starter-files/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

Comment: have you tried deleting node-modules, and package-lock.json and running `npm install` ?

Comment: should I delete the package.json as well?

Comment: no. package.json is required. When you hit `npm install` again node_modules and package-lock will be automatically created again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and installed two libs

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/url
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr2-cookies/v/0.9.1

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is React's not-so-subtle way of telling people to stop using back-end packages in their front-end applications. They have removed the default poly-fill for Nodejs packages. [Read more about the current state here.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756)